# Servicestack Ormlite seems to be ignoring my Database Schemas c#

Tags: c#, sql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Hi folks quick help required if possible i'm trying to do (what i thought would be simple) a quick query.

The object i'm using

```
 [Schema("Prospect")]
    [Alias("TrackedSource")]
    public class ProspectSource
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        [AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

       public int? ClientId { get; set; }

 public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

i'm running the following command

```
string source ="unknown";
int clientId = 10000;
  var foundSource = Db.Select<ProspectSource>(q => (q.Name.Contains(source.Trim()) || (q.Name.Contains(source.Trim()) && q.ClientId == clientId) && q.IsActive)).FirstOrDefault();
```

but running this gives me the following generated sql

```
SELECT "Id",  "ClientId", "Name", "IsActive"
FROM "TrackedSource"
WHERE (upper("Name") like '%UNKNOWN%' OR ((upper("Name") like '%UNKNOWN%' AND ("ClientId" = 10000)) AND "IsActive"=1))
```

and of course the error - TrackedSource can not be found is generated.

I was expected the following sql to be generated

```
SELECT "Id",  "ClientId", "Name", "IsActive"
FROM "Prospect"."TrackedSource"
WHERE (upper("Name") like '%UNKNOWN%' OR ((upper("Name") like '%UNKNOWN%' AND ("ClientId" = 10000)) AND "IsActive"=1))
```

anyone with any ideas why this could be happening

using latest version of Servicestack﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved from the **v4.0.39+** release of ServiceStack that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).